# What is solution of this error in babel-loader and pdfjs-dist?

Tags: reactjs, pdfjs-dist

**Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (1198:17)
File was processed with these loaders:
./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js

You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|         }
|         class PDFDocumentLoadingTask {

> ```
>       static #docId = 0;
> ```

|           constructor() {
|             this._capability = (0, _util.createPromiseCapability)();**